# SQL Server And/ Or and Parentheses Precedence Understanding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had written a sql query long time ago and when I was revisiting that query, I got confused in the where condition of the query. Here is the brief intro on what the sql should do: The sql tries to look for all the orders that were closed yesterday or all the orders that were  in open status and has been open for more than 10 days.

Here is the sql code

```
DECLARE           
@start_date as datetime,
@end_date as datetime

 SET @start_date =  dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0,getdate())-2, 0)

 SET @end_date =  dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0,getdate())-1, 0)

Select * from OrdersTable
---- all columns are coming from one table only           
Where 
(
  (Closed Date>=@start_date and Closed Date<@end_date and order_status='Closed' )
  or 
 (order_Status='Open')---this tells us the cases is open                                                                                
 and 
 datediff(ss,OrderStarDate,
   dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0))/86400.0 >= 10
```

)

NOW THE CONFUSION IS THIS...

after the 'or' condition in where clause everything should be under one parenthesis like below:

```
Select * from OrdersTable
 ----all columns are coming from one table only 
Where
(
   (Closed Date>=@start_date and Closed Date<@end_date and order_status='Closed' )
   or (order_Status='Open' ---In above query I mistakenly closed the parantheses here
   and 
  datediff(ss,OrderStarDate,
  dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0))/86400.0 >= 10

)---the Parentheses should have been closed here

)----The final parentheses like the above query no change here
```

So I tried my best to explain this question. If anyone can answer: Will my first query where I made mistake will still work as the second query (the correct one). The reason why I am asking is when I correct my sql,I get the same records as  when I run the wrong query....I am trying to get a logical answer why this is happening.

Comment: I read your query wrong the first time I read it. The two queries should be logically equivalent. A and B OR c and D should return the same result as (A and B) or (C and D), though it always helps to be explicit with brackets for readability.

Comment: @ZLK- Thanks so much:) This is what I was expecting but wasn't sure. I agree with putting explicit brackets for better understanding but I didn't do the first time.

Comment: Indeed. Though I think the enclosing brackets are unnecessary for a WHERE clause (i.e. you don't need `WHERE(..)`). Also, from the documentation on [`OR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql): "When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, OR operators are evaluated after AND operators."

Answer (score 0):

For better Understanding of your Question:

In your `where` clause you have  parenthesis

```
1. ( this means you have a group or enclosed condition with a two Contents 
     in or Operand

  2.() and this one is your first condition
     or 
  3.( while this one is your second condition with
     4. (Wrapper DateDiff
       5. ( second DateDiff inside the wrapper
        ) End Second DateDiff
     )End Wrapper

    ) End of second condition

) End here
```

Your Query will do the number `1` first off course but you have an enclosed in number `2` that's why the searching change to number `2` first. After the 2 is done then it will proceed to 3.

To explain it briefly, It will do first always in a `Close` and `Open` Parenthesis in every Operand.